# Saving output of analyses done using sapply to dataframe for later use

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I have a number of dataframes (in this example *df1*, *df2*, *df3*) that contain several variables (in this example *A*, *B*, *C*). The variables are the same in each dataframe. The first variable in each dataframe is skipped as that variable contains sample identifiers.
Using pieces of code that I found on the internet I managed to cobble something together that iterates through the variabels of each dataset (using *seq_along*), creates a boxplot of each variable for the different dataframes, and does Mann-Whitney U statistics. All using [sapply](/questions/tagged/sapply). So far so good. That part is working.

MWE:

```
#Example data
df1 = data.frame("ID"= make.unique(rep(letters, length.out = 50), sep=''),
      "A"=sample(1:200, 50, replace=T), "B"=sample(1:200, 50), "C"=sample(1:200, 50))
df2 = data.frame("ID"= make.unique(rep(letters, length.out = 50), sep=''),
      "A"=sample(1:100, 50, replace=T), "B"=sample(1:100, 50), "C"=sample(1:100, 50))
df3 = data.frame("ID"= make.unique(rep(letters, length.out = 50), sep=''),
      "A"=sample(1:500, 50, replace=T), "B"=sample(1:500, 50), "C"=sample(1:500, 50))

#Actual code 
sapply(seq_along(df1)[-1], function(i){
  y <- df1[, i]
  mydfp <- data.frame(y=c(df1[, i],df2[, i], df3[, i]), x=c(rep(1,length(df1[, i])),
                          rep(2, length(df2[, i])), rep(3, length(df3[, i]))))
#Create boxplots
  with(mydfp, {
  boxplot(y~x, xlab="X-axis", ylab="Y-axis", notch=TRUE, names=(c("df1", "df2",
          "df3")), varwidth=TRUE, las=2)
 points(y~jitter(x, 0.5), col='firebrick', pch=2, cex=0.5)
  })

#Do statistics
  testdf1vs2 <- wilcox.test(df1[, i], df2[, i])
  testdf1vs3 <- wilcox.test(df1[, i], df3[, i])
  testdf2vs3 <- wilcox.test(df2[, i], df3[, i])

  pvaluedf1vs2 <- testdf1vs2$p.value
  pvaluedf1vs3 <- testdf1vs3$p.value
  pvaluedf2vs3 <- testdf2vs3$p.value
  pvalueformatdf1vs2 <- format(pvaluedf1vs2, digits=2, nsmall=2)
  pvalueformatdf1vs3 <- format(pvaluedf1vs3, digits=2, nsmall=2)
  pvalueformatdf2vs3 <- format(pvaluedf2vs3, digits=2, nsmall=2)

#Add p-values to boxplot
  mtext(paste(colnames(df1)[i], ", p (df1 - df2): ", pvalueformatdf1vs2, " /
              p (df1 - df3): ", pvalueformatdf1vs3, " /
               p (df2 - df3): ", pvalueformatdf2vs3, sep="" ), side=3, line=0.5,
        at=2, cex=0.8)
      })
```

What I would like to do is to save all p-values (in this example *pvalueformatdf1vs2*, *pvalueformatdf1vs3*, *pvalueformatdf2vs3*) from the MWU statistics to a dataframe that I can use in subsequent steps (outside of the [sapply](/questions/tagged/sapply) function).

Example dataframe to be created:

```
  pvalueformatdf1vs2 pvalueformatdf1vs3 pvalueformatdf2vs3
A 0.05               0.04               0.03
B 0.02               0.01               0.009 
C 0.008              0.007              0.006
```

I have tried to create a dataframe and add to it with [rbind](/questions/tagged/rbind). However, R will give me an error, stating that the name of the dataframe is not within the scope. I have found options to use [sapply](/questions/tagged/sapply) to modify an existing dataframe and save that output, but now I need it to actually create and update a dataframe.
I can add the p-values to a list by adding:

```
l <- c(l, pvalueformatdf1vs2, pvalueformatdf1vs3, pvalueformatdf2vs3)
```

But that list only exists during the [sapply](/questions/tagged/sapply) function and cannot be used afterwards. It is probably possible to write the p-values to a text file with each iteration and the read that file back into R again but it would seem an inefficient way to go. I haven't looked into that option yet, as I hope that someone here will have a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to make your function return something: just add `return(c(pvalueformatdf1vs2=pvalueformatdf1vs2, pvalueformatdf1vs3=pvalueformatdf1vs3, pvalueformatdf2vs3=pvalueformatdf2vs3))` at the end of your function. And transpose the result of `sapply` if you want the results in columns.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that after the function ends, the dataframe with p-values no longer exists. I need the dataframe to stay after the function ends, so I can use the data in later analyses.

Comment: then you need to `assign` the result of `sapply` to an object: `my_pvalues <- sapply(...)`. Probably it would also be good for you to read a R tutorial.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Assigning the function to an object only saves the last p-values of all iterations. I have already been searching in diverse R tutorials before I asked my question here, because I could not come to an easy solution.
In a less efficient way I can write the p-values of each iteration to a file using:
write(c(pvalueformatdf1vs2, pvalueformatdf1vs3, pvalueformatdf2vs3), file = "data.txt", append = TRUE, ncolumns = 3, sep = " ")

and then read the text file back into a dataframe:
my_pvalues <- read.table("data.txt")

Not as elegant as I hoped but it works.